# Ember canary "Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You can only add a 'milestone' record to this relationship"

Tags: ember.js

I have the following controller:

```
Filters.FiltersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ["milestones"],
    selectedMilestone: null,
    selectedMilestoneChange: function() {
        if(!this.get('filterTypeSelected') || !this.get('selectedMilestone')) {
            return;
        }
        var filter = this.store.createRecord('filter', {
            type: 'milestone',
            value: this.get('selectedMilestone').get("id"),
            negate: this.get('filterTypeSelected').negate,
            milestone: this.store.find('milestone', this.get("selectedMilestone").get("id"))
        });
        filter.save();
        this.resetFilterCreator();
    }.observes('selectedMilestone')
});
```

Whenever the view changes the `selectedMilestone` property, it creates a new `filter` instance and saves it.

This worked until I upgraded to Ember-canary to use the query-parameters-new feature. After the upgrade the following error is thrown whenever the filter record is created:

> Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You can only add a 'milestone' record to this relationship

The error originates from

```
milestone: this.store.find('milestone', this.get("selectedMilestone").get("id"))
```

Model is:

```
Filters.Filter = DS.Model.extend({
    type: DS.attr('string'),
    value: DS.attr('string'),
    milestone: DS.belongsTo('milestone'),
    negate: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that (apparently in the newer Ember versions), the return from `this.store.find(...)` is a promise and thus not `instanceof Milestone`.

Instead you can either resolve the promise or use `this.store.getById('model', 'id')`. This, however, requires that the model has already been retrieved (which it is `onLoad` in my case).